# How to build the most efficient 5*5*5 power generation system?

Tags: starmade

To fill just a 5*5*5 space what would be the most efficient power generation configuration?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so apparently we can squeeze 9.9k power/s from this design (`P` stands for power generator, `.` stands for anything else):

```
PPP.P
.P.PP
P.P.P
PP.P.
P.PPP

..PP.
P....
P.P.P
....P
.PP..

PP.PP
P.P.P
.PPP.
P.P.P
PP.PP

.PP..
....P
P.P.P
P....
..PP.

P.PPP
PP.P.
P.P.P
.P.PP
PPP.P
```